# Python - Classes - Self Not Defined

Tags: python, class, self

Below I'm attempting to make a simple Keygen as a first project. Somewhere I'm getting the error the Self has not been defined.

I'm guessing it's probably something easy

```
import random

class KeyGenerator():
def __init__(self):

    length = 0
    counter = 0
    key = []
    Letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']



def KeyGen4(self):
    while self.counter != self.length:
        a = random.choice(self.Letters)
        print a #test
        r = (random.randint(0,1))
        print r #test
        if r == True:
            a = a.upper()
        else:
            pass
        self.key.append(a)
        self.counter += 1

    s = ''      
    self.key = s.join(key)
    print self.key
    return self.key

def start(self):
    selection = raw_input('[K]eygen4, [C]ustom length Keygen or [N]umbers? >')

    if selection == 'K' or 'k':
        length = 4
        keyGen4(self)

    elif selection == 'N' or 'n':
        KeyGenN(self)

    elif selection == 'C' or 'c':
        length = int(raw_input("Key Length: "))
    #KeyGen4(self) # Change later after creating method with more options

start(self)
```

Comment: `self.start()` instead of `start(self)`. You have done the same error for other methonds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your indention is wrong, but I assume this is only a copy-pasting issue.
2. That `start(self)` at the bottom doesn't make sense,
   and indeed `self` is not defined there. You should create an instance of the class, and then call its `start` method:

   ```
   KeyGenerator().start()

   # or 

   key_gen = KeyGenerator()
   key_gen.start()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. you miss indentation on every class-function
2. you must create an object of the class before you can call any of its functions

Your class should look like this

```
import random

class KeyGenerator():
    def __init__(self):

        length = 0
        counter = 0
        key = []
        Letters = ['a','b','c','d','e']

    def KeyGen4(self):
        while self.counter != self.length:
            a = random.choice(self.Letters)
            print a #test
            r = (random.randint(0,1))
            print r #test
            if r == True:
                a = a.upper()
            else:
                pass
            self.key.append(a)
            self.counter += 1

        s = ''      
        self.key = s.join(key)
        print self.key
        return self.key

    def start(self):
        selection = raw_input('[K]eygen4, [C]ustom length Keygen or [N]umbers? >')

        if selection == 'K' or 'k':
            length = 4
        self.keyGen4()

        elif selection == 'N' or 'n':
            self.KeyGenN()

        elif selection == 'C' or 'c':
            length = int(raw_input("Key Length: "))
        #KeyGen4(self) # Change later after creating method with more options

#now make an instance of your class
my_key_gen = KeyGenerator()
my_key_gen.start()
```

Please note that when calling class functions inside the class, you need to use `self.FUNCNAME`.  All class functions should take "self" as argument.  If that is their only argument then you simply call them with `self.func()`.  If they take arguments you still ommit the self, as `self.func(arg1, arg2)`

Comment: I appreciate the lengthy response! I forgot to make a instance of the class... I need to read a bit more so i can remember these things. Thank you!